# Use wifi from iPhone via thethering

Tags: 12.04, android, iphone, tethering

Im trying to get my friend to try out Elementary OS Luna (based on Ubuntu 12.04) but the problem at our school is that the wifi dosen't support Linux, only Windows, Mac and Android. Therefor I get my internet by connecting to wifi from my phone (Galaxy S II) and then thethering it to my computer. Can I do the same with an iPhone 5?

Comment: user149408 is correct, it should work, but wifi is OS independent and Linux should work as well as other OS

Answer (score 1):

The same should work with an iPhone. Just enable WiFi tethering in settings, then look that WiFi in Ubuntu and enter the connection password. (By the way, you should be able to connect to your school network in the same manner.)

Comment: What mine does does with my SII, it says that it´s a wired connection. So I never have to log into the wifi via the computer, I have done that via the mobil. And I then need the same thing done with an Iphone, because when I tried to get his Iphone to thether, it would only make a wifi hotspot. But a phone cannot be connected to a wifi and on the same time make i wifi network.

Comment: @RasmusPeterMathiesen: oh, then I misunderstood you, I thought you were tethering to your phone via WiFi and using your phone's 3G connection. That would indeed work with an iPhone in the same manner. I have used WiFi tethering with an iPhone; Ubuntu also reports it as a wired network but I never got that to work (though I didn't try seriously).